# Xcode 5 and Cocos2d issues

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I just upgraded to Xcode 5.  I began a new Cocos2d project and when I open just the basic initial program and run, I get the "cannot run on this device" (any of the simulators) and "choose a destination with supported architecture ..."

When I go into Build Settings I see the compiler for C++ is unsupported.  I change it to Default complier (Apple LLVM 5.0) and it seems to run, but I get 73 errors - and I have not even attempted to program anything yet.

Most are deprecation errors, but many are not.

Is there something else I should change?  Or is there an issue using cocos2d with Xcode 5.

I never had this previously - just a few deprecated files.

Comment: I just created new Cocos2d-Box2d project in Xcode 5 and I don't have any errors....I used Cocos2d 2.0...updating your cocos2d template fix all your issue.